# How to Compress Images on Server Side using jpegoptim

Tags: image

I need help uploading JPEG files to my server. I would also like to compress the uploaded files. Is this possible? Can `jpegoptim` help me?

Comment: What OS/language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It usually is possible to call external binaries from your program, but I'd say that in your case is not worth it. You will get a small decrease in file size, and a large increase in CPU usage. Furthermore, it might take a significant amount of man-hours to properly implement and test this feature, which in the end, you might not really need. Focus on the core functionality of your app, and optimize in the end.

Comment: But Google Page Speed Test Gives Me Error to Compress Images.
i am having VPS and only running 1 Site.
So i have Spear CPU and Memory.

Comment: I'd like to see these images that you claim are slowing your site. It might be the case that the pages are of a large resolution, and are shrunk down. If that's the case, you should resize your images to the resolution they are actually displayed on your site.